# How to get the full path for a local file in Firefox 3

Tags: jquery, python, html

I'm working on an intranet site, and would like to be able to click on a file (I'm not picky on how) and have the server "know" the filenme + path that I just picked.  The local path is relevent because the server hosting the application has the same mapped network drive as all of the clients, so x:\someplace\something.txt is the same thing client and server side.

The obvious way was the input type="file" etc method while disabling the actual upload.  The best that I've been able to come up with using this method, like countless others, is the filename.  Also note that the link in a very similar sounding question to the "accepted answer" involving some onBlur workaround is broken.

The tools that I'm working with are FF3, Python/Pylons (using Mako templates) server side, and jquery client side, and am open to anything that can capture a full path without a user typing it out.

Any Ideas?

TIA,
Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to do this?If the server is supposed to read the file with the path,why not simply upload it? Is it so large that it takes am unaceptable amount  of time on an intranet? Anyway, you can probably do this with a java applet embedded.

Comment: I suppose that an upload really wouldn't hurt anything... and if it does there's always deleting the files once processed at least making a note of the filename used for documentation.  Thanks for the response.. I accept that it's either impossible or not worth it to get the path name from the DOM on FF3.